# Twitter Bootstrap affix weird behavior

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, affix

I'm trying to make a pinned menu in the left column, but the affix plugin works weird in my case: http://jsfiddle.net/AlexeyKosov/753ofx5x/
Try to scroll to bottom and back, when you're scrolling back, the menu jumps to top.
What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <div class="panel panel-default menu">
                    <div class="list-group">
                        <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Item 1</a>
                        <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Item 2</a>
                        <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Item 3</a>
                        <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Item 4</a>
                    </div>
                </div>          
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <div class="content">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        footer
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.content {
    height: 1000px;
}
.footer {
    background: #eee; 
    height: 1000px;
}
.menu {
    width: 250px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('.menu').affix({
        offset: {
            top: 100,
            bottom: 1000
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `affix`:

avoid scripts

In bootstrap itself there is a inbuilt class called `affix` which consist of following css:

```
.affix {
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/WtiIPVNo65)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <div class="panel panel-default menu affix">
                    <div class="list-group">
                        <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Item 1</a>
                        <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Item 2</a>
                        <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Item 3</a>
                        <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Item 4</a>
                    </div>
                </div>          
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <div class="content">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        footer
    </div>
```

Comment: You should explain a bit more.

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap affix, but call it from javascript rather than data attributes. Your example doesn't handle the footer.

Comment: From what your question asks, this does exactly that... Remove your JS and it will work...

Comment: I removed js but it still doesn't work. I guess you don't understand what the problem is. Do you see gray footer in my example? The menu must not overlap it.

Comment: It will overlaps see the DEMO given

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add

```
.affix-bottom {
    position: absolute;
}
```